connecting to postgres container within a spring boot application
I have following dokcer-compose.yml file to create service:
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:

and I also have application.yml file for my spring boot application:
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer
    username: user
    password: password
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet

I can run my docker and here is output:
2024-04-09 08:54:48.470 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-04-09T08:54:48.471017704Z 2024-04-09 08:54:48.470 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-04-09T08:54:48.471019389Z 2024-04-09 08:54:48.470 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-04-09T08:54:48.473862977Z 2024-04-09 08:54:48.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-04-09T08:54:48.478177411Z 2024-04-09 08:54:48.478 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-09 08:54:35 UTC
2024-04-09T08:54:48.481791830Z 2024-04-09 08:54:48.481 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

but when I try to connect to my db within my spring boot app, I am getting following errors, I search and applied different solutions, but not successful.
2024-04-09T10:57:24.705+02:00  INFO 32588 --- [spring-boot-example] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-09T10:57:25.740+02:00 ERROR 32588 --- [spring-boot-example] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]


You mapped the external port to 5332 not 5432.

Thanks I was thinking that It would search from port 5332 till 5432, Isn't the case?

No it isn't. You are mapping external port 5332 on internal port 5432. There is no searching. What made you think that?

if you provide the answer, I will accept this, otherwise I will delete the question.

You are connection to localhost:5432 while in your compose file you are mapping port 5332 to internal port 5432. That is what the ports: 5332:5432 is doing.
To connect you would need to connect to localhost:5332 or change the mapping to 5432:5432. Either way will work.
